# How to add a button in Jupyter Lab Launcher for a Voilà notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, voila

I'm using Jupyter Lab with Voilà to render a user interface.

When opening my dashboard, here is what I need to do.

[image]

The problem is that I'd like to have a button in the Jupyter Lab Launcher to open the dashboard directly.

[image]

1. Is it possible to add a button in the Launcher?
2. How to cable it with Voilà?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's the [jupyterlab extensions guide](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html). I'm not sure how to do this but imagine it's buried in here somewhere.

Comment: There is an example for adding buttons to the launcher: https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-examples#launcher